# Why is the element replaced

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm curious as to why the element is replaced, rather than added at the end of the div...?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>

    <h1>JavaScript in Body</h1>

    <div id="demo">
    <h1>A paragraph will appear below</h1>
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<p>My First JavaScript</p>"'>Insert a paragraph</button>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `=` with `+=` to append innerHTML instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` replace the inner content of the element instead use `.appendChild()`